# vite replace an import statement

Tags: javascript, vite

I have a vue file

```
// myComponent.vue
import { something } from 'some-module'
...
```

I want to replace this import statement into

```
import { something } from '@/utils/myModule'
```

in case when running the vitest command.
Do we have some plugin which I can use to get the above result?

Answer (score 5):

Ok its working

```
// vite.config.js
    alias: [
          {
            find: /some-module/,
            replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/utils/someModuleFake.ts', import.meta.url)),
          },
          {
            find: '@',
            replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
          },
        ],
```

Comment: This answer saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jsconfig.json file to achieve this.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/utils/*": ["componentpath/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[vite-plugin-filter-replace](https://github.com/ikeq/vite-plugin-filter-replace) can solve this problem. Add follow config in vite.config.ts

```
import filterReplace from 'vite-plugin-filter-replace';
export default {
    plugins: [filterReplace([{
        filter: /\.vue$/,
        replace: {
            from: /some-module/g,
            to: '@/utils/myModule'
        },   
    }], {
       enforce: 'pre',
       apply: 'build'
    }
    )],
};
```